# How to check if an integer is linear combination of elements in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, boolean, nested-loops

How to check if an integer can be expressed as linear combination of elements in a given array of length n? Currently I can code for the specific case when n=2, but I don't know how to code when n is unknown.

This is the function when n=2 (when there are only two elements in the array):

```
bool check(int array[], int n, int value){//n values in the array //    

  for (int i=1; i<array[0]; i++){
     for (int j=1; j<array[1]; j++){
        if ((i*array[0]+j*array[1])%value==0){
            printf("x=%d, y=%d, i=%d, j=%d\n", array[0], array[1], i, j);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So... I suppose the coefficients can be only integers, otherwise it won't make sense.

Comment: @DavidBowling That what I meant, yes.

Comment: yes the coefficient are all integers.@EugeneSh @ David Bowling

Comment: Use recursion to handle arrays of any length.

Comment: @Barmar can you specify how to use recursion here please? I'm not very experienced with recursion. Thanks!

Comment: @YH Then I think you should study it and try to figure it out yourself. Basic idea: You already know how to solve the problem for 2 elements. How is the solution for 3 elements related to this? Can you express that recurrence relationship generally?

Comment: @YH SO is not  programming school.

Comment: Hmmm. It looks like your algorithm reports that 2 is not a linear combination of {1, 0}. Have a look at: `for (int i=1; i<array[0]; i++)  {  for (int j=1; j<array[1]; j++){}}`.

Comment: Hey @YH. If you find my answer solved your problem, could you mark it as the accepted answer? It helps people that may be having the same problem solve it.

Comment: @RX9 Sorry I haven't login for a while. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember from my first-year discrete math courses that `n` is a linear combination of `x` and `y` if and only if n is a multiple of the `gcd(x,y)` (i.e. if `value % gcd(x,y) == 0`)

you can use this notion as a powerful asset in your code.

The moral here is to calculate the gcd between all the elements in your set and keep checking if `value` is divisible by the `gcd(x,y)`. If it is, then return `1`, else `0`.

I'll leave the implementation of the `gcd()` function to you (there are many examples of it online), but here is how you can incorporate it in your existing code:

```
bool check(int array[], int n, int value){
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {            // notice we only iterate up to n - 1
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (value % gcd(array[i], array[j]) == 0) {
               printf("x=%d, y=%d, i=%d, j=%d\n", array[0], array[1], i, j);
               return 1;
            }
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  This may also work well with `array[], value <= 0`.  May have a problem with `array[i], array[j] == 0`.

Comment: This algorithm will produce false negatives, e.g. in case `n=7`, `array=[6, 15, 10]`. You should compute gcd of the entire array, not pairwise gcd’s