# Check if an integer can be represented as a linear combination of integers in array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to solve a problem where given an integer `n`, and an array of integers `a` -- can `n` be represented as a linear combination of elements from `a` such that the coefficients are **positive** integers as well.

I saw [C: check if an integer is linear combination of elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583925/c-check-if-an-integer-is-linear-combination-of-elements-in-an-array) and implemented it as such in C, but it doesn't work in all cases.

```c
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if (a == 0) {
    return b;
  }
  return gcd(b % a, a);
}

bool can_be_changed(const int a[], int len, int val) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (val % gcd(a[i], a[j]) == 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

But, if `a = {4,5,6}` and `val=7` the code will return true as `gcd(4,5) = 1` and `7 % gcd(4,5) == 0` will evaluate to `true` thus returning `true` which it shouldn't.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Isn't `6+5-4` a linear combination with integer coefficients (+1, +1, and -1)?

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, the coefficients must be positive ints. Edited OP.

Comment: So is the algorithm in that link designated for positive integers only? There is even a comment under the answer in that link, saying that it works well for negative integers as well.

Comment: Cannot be solved by just using GCD, you should solve it like a Knapsack Problem.

Comment: @goodvibration No, I'm trying to reach a modification of that.

Comment: @BahattinUngormus I'll check out the knapsack problem

Comment: The algorithm in that answer won't work; your version is NP-hard.

Comment: If all numbers are positive and `n` is small enough, then you can use dynamic programming. See the idea here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR: [easiest algorithm is here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unbounded-knapsack-repetition-items-allowed/), most efficient algorithm is explained below.

When you restrict the coefficients to positive integers, this problem is NP-complete (as long as `len` is part of the input and not fixed). So a truly *efficient* solution isn't going to happen. (It's called the Unbounded Subset Sum Problem, if you want to google around; [a proof of its hardness is here](https://folk.idi.ntnu.no/mlh/algkon/hard.pdf).)

[The most efficient algorithm I've found is from this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.04712.pdf):

[image: algorithm in pseudocode]

The ⊕<sub>t</sub> operation is a "capped sumset", also described in the paper: it basically operates like this (sketched in Python):

```
def capped_sumset(a, b, t): # a, b sets of naturals, t natural
    a0 = a | {0}
    b0 = b | {0}
    return {
        x+y
            for x in a0
            for y in b0
        if x+y <= t
    }
```

The hardest part about implementing this in C is going to be all the set operations; once you have a good implementation of sets of integers, the algorithm itself isn't too bad.

If you don't care about efficiency, of course, you can use the "classic dynamic program" mentioned in the base case of the algorithm; [you can find a detailed explanation with examples in several programming languages here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unbounded-knapsack-repetition-items-allowed/). But be prepared for an exponential running time!